# Displaying <h:inputText> and <h:selectOneMenu> as <f:param> of <h:outputFormat>

Tags: jsf-2, param, messageformat

I'm using `<h:outputFormat>` to format a message.

```
<h:outputFormat value="Sent {0} to {1} different people">
    ...
</h:outputFormat>
```

I would like to display a `<h:inputText>` in place of parameter `{0}` and a `<h:selectOneMenu>` with list of numbers from 1-50 in place of parameter `{1}`.

Is it possible to do so using `<f:param>`, or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the `<f:param>` of the standard JSF implementation. This is however possible with the [`<o:param>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/param) of JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) which has enhanced the `<f:param>` with the support of supplying real JSF code as format parameter.

Here's how you can solve it using `<o:param>`:

```
<h:outputFormat value="Sent {0} to {1} different people" escape="false">
    <o:param>
        <h:inputText value="#{bean.input}" />
    </o:param>
    <o:param>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.number}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{bean.numbers}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </o:param>
</h:outputFormat>
```